# Accessing form class control's reference in custom control class

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, custom-controls

I want to somehow pass the reference (from form1.cs class) and access the reference of datagridview1 which is used only in Form1.cs in my declaration of customdatagridview. The reason is that in every form of my Windows application, there will be a new Datagridview (all with different names), and their reference would be used for some purpose by this custom datagridview. Is it possible to do it. If not, what should be the alternative.

```cs
public partial class smartdatagridview : DataGridView
{
    public smartdatagridview()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    
    private TextBox textBox;

    protected override void OnEnter(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnEnter(e);
        CurrentCell = this[0, 0]; 
        BeginEdit(true);
    }
    
    protected override void OnEditingControlShowing(DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnEditingControlShowing(e);

        if (CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0 && e.Control is TextBox)
        {
            textBox = (TextBox)e.Control;
            textBox.TextChanged -= Text_Changed;
            textBox.KeyDown -= Key_down;
            textBox.Enter -= Key_Enter;
            textBox.TextChanged += Text_Changed;
            textBox.KeyDown += Key_down;
            textBox.Enter +=Key_Enter;
        }
        else
        {
            textBox = null;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnCellEndEdit(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnCellEndEdit(e);
        if (textBox != null)
        {
            textBox.TextChanged -= Text_Changed;
            textBox.KeyDown -= Key_down;
            textBox.Enter -= Key_Enter;
            textBox = null;
        }
        if (this.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)  ***// error*** 
            {
                this.CurrentCell.Value = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString(); ***// error*** 
                dataGridView1.Visible = false;  ***// error*** 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I still don't get why your gridview needs access to another gridview in another form. But anyway, you need to provide that reference to the former in some way, e.g. using a constructor-argument. For example `var grid = new smartdatagridview(form1Instance.TheGrid)`.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain ,    on every Form1.cs , form2.cs , form3.cs , there will be 2 datagridviews . one is custom datagridview which is a custom control and the other is specific to the form which is used to hold table dataset in its memory

Comment: okay, as mentioned before you need to provide the grid via a constructor-argument to your custom grid.

Comment: Instaed of all that irrelevant code like `OnEditingControlShowing` you should show where you actually create the grids and the forms

Comment: "which is used to hold table dataset in its memory" it is unadviseable to use controls as data storage. The purpose of UI elements (especially datagridview) is to display data. the storage should be in an extra collection or other data structure that is independent of any UI elements. This data structure should be passed else where it is also needed, not the displaying UI element

Comment: The last `if` block is in the wrong place and context. Move it to the Form which hosts the `smartdatagridview1` and `dataGridView1`. Have it in the `CellEndEdit` event or `CellValueChanged` event of the `smartdatagridview` instance. Separate the custom control functionalities and its implementations.